# Wrap CustomValidator in a UserControl, but allow access to it

Tags: asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I've got a UserControl that is essentially just a TextBox with optional built-in validators to it.  At the moment this is just a RequiredFieldValidator and RegexValidator.  It's easy to just expose properties on the UserControl which get passed through to these validators and allow me to set the RegEx for example.

Now I'd like to add a CustomValidator and allow the user to add a server-side validation function... and this is causing me some trouble.  What is the proper syntax for this?  I tried just adding a ServerValidateEventHandler property, but when I try to use this I get a runtime error:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventHandler' from its string representation 'valState_ServerValidate' for the 'ServerValidate' property.
```

Do I need to expose a delegate in some other way?  This should be easy... I'm missing one little key.  Please note, I'm trying to add a CustomValidator to a page which uses the UserControl... I want the user to specify a handler for custom validation on the usercontrol itself.  (yes, it's a bit of a Frankencontrol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution; instead of a public property, use a public event!

```
public delegate void ServerValidateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ServerValidateHandler ServerValidate;
```

ASP.NET will expose the event with the "On" prefix - so "ServerValidate" becomes "OnServerValidate"

For example, in the ASPX or ASCX you would enter: *OnServerValidate="MyMethod"* where MyMethod is the custom method that you want to execute, and it has the signature defined by the ServerValidateHandler delegate:

```
protected void MyMethod(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something...
}
```

If you wanted to pass special information to your handler, you could create your own eventargs class (e.g. *MyEventArgs : EventArgs*), and update the delegate to pass that type instead of EventArgs.

If you need to access the handler yourself, you could do the following (this code assumes that there will be at most only one callback method, but you could modify it to allow more by using a collection of handlers instead):

```
    public delegate void ServerValidateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    private ServerValidateHandler _handler;
    public event ServerValidateHandler ServerValidate
    {
        add { _handler = value; }
        remove { _handler = null; }
    }
```

Of course, if you don't need any of these extras, then it simplifies to:

```
public event EventHandler ServerValidate;
```